# Trouble with strchr in C

Tags: c, strchr

I can't work out why `Strchr()` is not working in my function. I need to see if the users guess matches any of the letters in a hidden word. It is a Hangman game.

```
int guessLetter(char* word, int* guessedLetters)
{
    char guess[20];
    char *s;

    printf("Enter your guess: ");
    scanf("%s", &guess);

    s = strchr (word, guess);
    printf("%s", s);

    if (s != NULL) {
        printf ("Good Guess\n");
    } else {
        printf ("Bad Guess\n");
    }

}
```

No matter if the guess is right or wrong, my `else` statement is being activated. My `printf` shows that `s` is being given the value of `Null` no matter if the character is in the word or not.

So I guess my problem is with this part of the code:

```
s = strchr (word, guess);
```

I am new to C, so I am sure I am just missing something very basic. I have tried to search the web as much as I can, but I don't really seem to be able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [`const char * strchr ( const char * str, int character )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) takes an int input in second parameter. not a char[20]. also your function is returning an undefined int value atm..

Comment: Parameters of strchr are a character array and a character ( not a character array).

Comment: Also, remove the `&` from your `scanf`. Don't add `&` when scanning/printing a `%s`.

Comment: you may need [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

Comment: @amdixon. Thanks, it took me a bit to understand why it would need an int parameter but i understand now.

Comment: by the way, have you `#include <string.h>` in your code?  If so, you'd get an error on using **strchr(3)** with incorrect parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) takes an `int` as 2nd argument but you are passing a `char*`. You Turn on your compiler warnings.

What you wanted is to loop over the `word` to see if any of the characters are in `guess`.

```
s = 0;
for(size_t i=0; word[i]; i++) {
    s = strchr (guess, word[i]);
    if(s) break; //Found a match
}
```

This would break on the first match and you can modify it if you want to check for *all* characters in `word`.

There's an argument mismatch in scanf call too:

```
scanf("%s", &guess);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", guess);
```

`scanf` expects a `char*` for format string `%s` but you are passing `char(*)[20]` i.e. `&guess` is of type `char (*)[20]`.

Comment: I think i understand a bit better but i dont see in the loop you gave me where it compares anything to 'guess'
Oh nvm, i see you changed the loop to add 'guess'.

Comment: @Xarigizel Mistake. Edited post now. Also, note that `word` has to be a null terminated string. If it isn't, then you need to pass the number of characters in it as another argument and loop over that number.

Comment: Thanks for the help, for some reason i find it so much harder to understand C compared to C++/Java. Thanks for all the pointers, will make changes now and see if it all works for me

Comment: This looks an awful lot like `strcspn()`.